# How can I connect two monitors to my laptop?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a lapton ThinkPad E14 with one HDMI and one type-c thunderbold port. This type-c port is used as power plugged.
How can I plug two monitors Benq GW2780-T with ports HDMI (v1.4) - 1, DisplayPort (v1.2) - 1, VGA - 1?

At my work monitors are connected to the laptop via type-c and at the same time with monitor used as also a power supply. Can I connect the same way or I shoud have monitor with some power over type-c function or something like this? For instance, connect one monitor via HDMI and another via type-c? Would a monitor connected via type-c be a power source for the laptop in my case?
Maybe I can buy some dock station or HDMI switch? If yes, which type should I buy?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using an USB-C hub with power passthrough. This would allow you to use your USB-C port to provide power and an HDMI output without getting new monitors. I'd specifically recommend [this hub from Baseus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B1PT5FVM): it has a dual HDMI 2.1 ports and power passthrough, which will allow you to use it as a one-cable solution for attaching to your computer.

[image]